# Getting compilation error while trying to sort an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, delegates, integer

I was doing homework in C# that required sorting an array. I could sort an array of integers using

```
Array.sort<int>(a, delegate(int x, int y) { return y-x;});
```

However if i want to do it from certain position and certain length

```
Array.sort<int>(a, 0, m, delegate(int x, int y) { return y-x;});
```

I get compilation error: "Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer' because it is not a delegate type".
I have solved the problem just by using

```
Array.sort<int>(a, 0, m);
```

and doing all other stuff backwards. Why it was giving me an error, and how can change it to work?

Thanks for help

Comment: Try to find the method you are calling on MSDN, and see what the types of its arguments are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method the first example is calling has the signature:

```
Array.Sort(int[] array, Comparison<int> comparison)
```

The delegate you are using is for the Comparison. There is not an overload of `Array.Sort` that has a index, length **and** Comparison.

The method you are trying to call has the following signature:

```
Array.Sort(int[] array, int index, int length, IComparer<int> comparer)
```

**Note IComparer, not Comparison**

If you need custom sorting. You will need to create a class that implements [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) as this is what the 4th parameter is expecting.

Alternatively, try the `.OrderByDescending` extension method which is available when you include `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thank you for the `.OrderByDescending()`, I have been looking for that for a while!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a custom comparer, pass a null as the 4th argument.

If you do, you need a parameter that specifically inherits from IComparer -- you can't just use an anonymous delegate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx